# Name and Mechanism of this Reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

#### Problem

> Find the product **X** in this reaction -
> [image]

#### Answer

> [image]

#### Question

**After seeing the solution**, I came up with the following mechanism for the reaction -
[image]

I am not sure if my mechanism is correct, nor do I understand *why* such a rearrangement takes place. There are no reagents used, the compound is only heated, and I couldn't understand why the old bonds had to break to form new ones. Please clarify -
If my proposed mechanism is correct or not,
If it is, why the reaction occurs this way, and
If the above reaction has a name or not.

Comment: What is the source of this question?

Comment: This looks like a sigmatropic rearrangement though ( I think)

Comment: It is from a FIITJEE AITS paper for JEE Advanced (an engineering entrance exam in India).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Claisen_rearrangement

Comment: @orthocresol Thank you! I was aware of Claisen rearrangement, but I'd seen it only on phenyl allyl ethers till now.